# Add class to div in jQuery based on a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I admit not being so great with JavaScript.

I've been tasked to build a utility that will run a check to see if a campaign date is going to expire in 2 weeks or less and add a class if it's going to.

The date is coming from a service and it's built (datatables map) as follows.
The data is coming back undefined but that's a different issue.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated because I don't seem to be having any luck whatsoever.

Initially I had a date object in there but wasn't sure it was necessary.

```
/*HTML Rendered Out for that table cell (there are multiple but this is how it 
comes out*/
 <td class=" campaign_start_date small-screen small-screen-2-col">06/14/2017 - 
 <div class="campaign-end-date">06/29/2017</div></td>
```

[image]
     JS
    //Datatables Code & modified for our project

```
{title:ax.L(114), class:'campaign_start_date small-screen small-screen-2-col', data:function(row, type, val, meta) {

  var campaignEndDate = ax.Utils.deNull(row.campaign_end_date, '');
  campaignEndDate = ax.Utils.RFCFormat(campaignEndDate, { excludeTime: true });
  var campaignStartDate = ax.Utils.deNull(row.campaign_start_date, '');
  campaignStartDate = ax.Utils.RFCFormat(campaignStartDate, { excludeTime: true });
  var campaignDateString;

  if (campaignEndDate && campaignStartDate ) {
    campaignDateString = campaignStartDate  + ' - ' + '<div class="campaign-end-date">' + ax.Utils.campaignEndDateAlert(campaignEndDate)  + '</div>';      
  } else {
    if (!campaignEndDate && campaignStartDate) {
      campaignDateString = campaignStartDate +  ' - ? ';
    } 

    else if (!campaignStartDate && campaignEndDate) { 
      campaignDateString = ' ? - ' +  campaignEndDate;
    }
    else {
      campaignDateString = ' ';
    }
  }
  return campaignDateString

  //My attempt at doing this from the Utility file - the code that i'm having no luck with.

  publicMethods.campaignEndDateAlert = function (data) {
    var campaignDateEnd = data.campaign_end_date;
    var $orderTable = $('#order-table');
    var $campaignDate = $orderTable.find('.campaign-end-date')

    if (campaignDateEnd <= campaignDateEnd + 86400000) {
      $campaignDate.addClass('green');
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like jquery

Comment: I'm not sure what `ax.utils` are... I found [this](https://dynamicsaxadmin.codeplex.com/). But focussing on the last function, I'm pretty sure that `$campaignDate` holds more than one element. There is (for sure) more than one `.campaign-end-date` in the whole table. Then, you have the date problem... Your comparision `(campaignDateEnd <= campaignDateEnd + 86400000)` can only be `false`... Whatever the date is.

Comment: Thanks, the ax.utils is just namespaced for our project. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok... So edit your question by posting the relevant HTML (the rendered HTML please) and how is triggered `campaignEndDateAlert` function.

Comment: Ooops.. Comparison can only be `true` (correction on my previous comment). You comparison simplified : `(a <= a+10)` -- It should be more something like `(campaignDateEnd <= now + twoWeeks)`.

Comment: Thank you, I've included the HTML of that table cell as well as a screen grab (it's the second to last td)

Comment: Ok... Now what is missing is how the `campaignEndDateAlert` function is triggered. Is it a button? A `hover`? Is it running on each rows on `load`?

Comment: Yes, sorry - it would be on the campaignEndDate variable (how the other ax.utils are). Edited, hope that helps.